# find all documents where starthour and startminute falls between documents starthour and endhour

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to find all the documents where the current time falls between startour and endhour of the document. I have set different field for hour and minute. 
My schema

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
    startHour: { type: Number},
    endHour: { type: Number},
    startMinute: { type: Number},
    endMinute: { type: Number}
})
```

I have written below find query which is not working. Here hour value and minute value are coming from http query I have converted them to int before using in query

```
find({
    $and : [
                { $or: [{starthour : { $lt: hour}}, 
                    { $and : [ {starthour: { $eq : hour}}, {startMinute: { $gt: minute}}]}
                ]},
                { $or: [{endHour : { $gt: nsh}}, 
                    { $and : [ {endhour: { $eq : hour}}, {endMinute: { $gt: minute}}]}
                ]},
            ],
        })
```

This should return all the documents where (hour is greater than and less than starthour and endhour) or (if starthour or endhour is equal to hour than startminute should be greater than minute ).

Comment: Why not make life a lot easier and simply express `start` and `end` being from the "minutes in the day". Each hour has 60 minutes so from 8:00am to 5:00pm would be `start: 480, end: 1020`. And then you just express your "current minutes" in the query to see if that falls between the document range. Much easier than trying to juggle hours and minutes in separate fields. And uses a lot less storage as well.

Comment: That is a good option. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is:

1. Check you hour is equal to endHour or not, In case of not set the
   isMinMatch true.
2. If not equal then check that make sure your minute is not greater then you endMinute.
3. Then make sure that you hours come between start and end hours and isMinMatch is true.
4. Remove the isMinMatch from result.

So i am using mongo aggregate to achieve this.

```
var hour = 11;
var minute = 0;
db.getCollection('testHours').aggregate([
{ $addFields: {  
    isMinMatch : {   
        $cond : [{ $eq : [ "$endHour", hour ] } , { $gte : [ "$endMinute" , minute]  }, true ] 
     } 
  }
},
{$match: {startHour : { $lte: hour}, endHour : { $gte: hour}, isMinMatch: true } },
{ $project : { isMinMatch: 0 } }
])
```

Comment: lets say time hour value is 19 and minute is 25 and starthour is 15:00 and endhour is 20:00. In this case last condition {endMinute : { $gte: minute}, will fail. That is why I am checking LT and EQ condition separately.

Comment: Updated my answer now please check again.